# What is the difference between the nuget packages System.Data.Sqlite and Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, nuget, system.data.sqlite

I currently included System.Data.Sqlite and use ExecuteNonQuery() and parameterized queries.
That requires LINQ and EntityFramework 6 which i don't use.

I would like to know if i can remove System.Data.Sqlite and use the SQLite v3.13.0 NuGet package instead, or do i loose access to parameterized queries and ExecuteNonQuery() if I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not include any method like `ExecuteNonQuery()` or support for parameterized queries, at least using the objects that you'll find in a standard .Net library.  Those interfaces are part of the .Net wrappers around the basic sqlite library.

The [SQLite v3.13.0 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite/3.13.0) contains the native compilations of the C-source library.  It does not include any interop library suitable for direct inclusion in a managed .Net project.